# Property .. does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ..'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I am attempting to add a custom prop to a custom styled-component:

```
interface Props {
  image?: string;
  title?: string;
  subtitle?: string;
  background?: string;
}

export function CardWide({
  image, title, subtitle, background
}: Props) {
  return (
    <CardContainer background={background}>
```

My styled component background that I passed through looks like this:

```
interface Props {
  background?: string;
}

const Card = styled.div<Props>`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-top: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 524px;
  background: ${props => props.background}
```

However, I receive the following error:

[image]

It feels like I've done everything that I needed to, but I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: is  that a `typo`?    `background: string;`  change to  `background?: string;` in your interface props

Comment: ah yes, @debugger (it was background?: string; before but I was trying to debug) It makes no difference to that error unfortunately. I've just updated the post now.

Answer (score -1):

Does this code sandbox help ?

https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-butterfly-4jjo0n?file=/src/App.tsx:312-320

Let me know if you need more help

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).